# How can I retrieve the result if I got a match of not in my MongoDB using a bash script

Tags: bash, mongodb, return-value

I look up a certain query in my MongoDB and echo the result. The output looks always the same:

`MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connection to: foo_collection
bye`

When I echo the result in a .txt file, I can see that an additional line is printed which gives me the desired result after the above mentioned string.

How can I get the result without the workaround by saving the echo of the result to a .txt file?

**UPDATE**

It seems, that mongodb produces a second time output after the connection information. I am only interested in the second output, how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

From `man mongo` :

> --quiet
>          Silences output from the shell during the connection process.

For instance, the following will only print the json result :

```
mongo --quiet --eval "printjson(db.getSiblingDB('myDB').getCollectionNames())"
```